# How to use all features in rpart?

Tags: r, decision-tree, document-classification, rpart

I'm using the *rpart* package for decision tree classification. I have a data frame with around 4000 features (columns). I want to use all features in `rpart()` for my model. How can I do that? Basically, `rpart()` will ask me to use the function in this way:

```
dt <- rpart(class ~ feature1 + feature2 + ....)
```

My features are words in documents so I have more than 4k features. Each feature is represented by a word. Is there any possibility to use all features without writing them?

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out:

```
dt <- rpart(class ~ ., data)
```

"." represents all features.

Answer (score 1):

The `caret` library is really useful because you can easily apply different models and compare their performance.  It can call `rpart` but uses a slightly different syntax to include all features.

```
library(caret)

library(data.table)

mt <- data.table(mtcars)

tr <- train(x=mt[,-'hp', with=FALSE], y = mt[, hp], method='rpart')

plot(tr$finalModel)
text(tr$finalModel)
```

Using all 4000 features for a decision tree could result in overfitting, especially if your number of observations is not huge.  `Caret` provides built-in cross-validation.  You might also want to look at `model='rf'` for random forests.